Does POTUS have the power to jail political rivals, dissidents, or "legislative opponents"?
It is claimed in a November 6th, 2024 instagram post by Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez that

in regimes like that, it is not uncommon to jail political dissidents or legislative opponents.. this is the world we very realistically may be entering

Question
Does POTUS have the power to "jail political/legislative opponents" or is this an unrealistic exaggeration?
What I know so far
My (layperson's) understanding is that:

the separation of powers helps prevent instances of tyranny by ensuring checks and balances,
constitutional protections should ensure minimal protections and that bogus laws can't be (easily) invented in order to entrap opponents, and
judicial oversight would necessitate multiple different bodies all with different mandates to conspire in order to carry out such an act

Note

Alternative video source (slightly
easier to navigate to relevant section of video - statements at approximately 1 minute).


De jure or de facto power? What one may (is allowed to) do by law vs. what one can (is able to) do?

Possible duplicate of https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/42357/can-a-us-president-have-someone-sent-to-prison

For the sake of clarity: are you asking whether POTUS could do this personally and unilaterally, or indirectly by stacking the justice system? My interpretation is the former, but at least one user has gone with the latter interpretation and had their answer deleted as a result. Perhaps you could clear this up for us?

In India, we have a saying - the process is the punishment.
That is, you don't even need to convict a political opponent under a case - the whole process of foisting a real / fake case on them, arresting them with huge media publicity, and continue lambasting them in the media as they go through the judicial process trying to defend themselves is itself a punishing process that can be enough to distract a political opponent.
In fact, we saw this with Trump too, pre-election - he was embroiled in multiple cases, with lots of negative publicity, and you could see that he and his campaign really felt hassled fighting court cases and facing the public at the same time. (Note: I am not claiming the cases against him were without merit).
While there are enough checks and balances in the system to prevent an autocrat from freely using State power against an opponent, the system is also flexibly built under the assumption that only leaders with democratic values will be wielding those powers (but, as we are finding out in this millennium, that isn't true any more and autocratic leaders do tend to abuse the system a lot).
As President of the US, Trump will have a lot of influence over all investigating agencies and even on the judiciary (through judicial appointments). He can certainly abuse this power to harass his political opponents including jailing his opponents with real / fake cases. How much he abuses his power will depend on his own idea of how much power he thinks "the majority" have given him, how much space the democratic institutions allow him to abuse this power and how much the opposition in the US can mobilise the people against him to make him think twice about misusing the system.

This example illustrates exactly the opposite of what you are saying. It is pretty clear that Trumps prosecution did not hurt him politically. It would make your point much stronger if you took someone who didn't manage to successfully run for president while being prosecuted.

@Kvothe - It hurt him immensely. Imagine how big a landslide he would have had if his attention hadn't been somewhat divided?

That's a more solid answer, IMHO.  He can certainly try to launch investigations, especially if there is any substance to any accusations - like say tax evasion.  After all, he does have precedents on his side there.

@Kvothe Since the list of US Presidents who have multiple criminal cases in progress at the time of election has precisely one entry, that's not really possible. But it was very well reported earlier this year that whilst Biden was on the campaign trail, Trump was forced to be sat in court. That he managed to get elected anyway is not in question, but it is also unquestionable that it reduced the number of days he could attend campaign rallies. If you think campaign rallies don't achieve anything then of course you might be right.

@Graham I've been on the receiving end of a baseless prosecution (albeit for economic competition rather than political), and the process hurts one's ability to compete immensely. The psychological stress is massive. Of course, now that the political establishment has practiced with the tactic, this list is very likely to grow in the future.

the process is the punishment => very well said. The ICC has the exact same issue.

Another example is Bob McDonald, who was financially ruined fighting a case brought by Jack Smith (the same one who was chosen to prosecute Trump's documents case before it was thrown out for him not being legally appointed). McDonald's case was ultimately overturned by the Supreme Court in a 9-0 ruling, but his political career was ruined because he simply didn't have any money left. He even had to sell his home to cover his court costs. Smith has a long history of prosecuting these political hit-piece cases that ultimately get overturned.

@Valorum "It hurt him immensely. Imagine..." - I prefer to work with empirical data rather than imaginary data, and we just don't really know how much of an effect it had on the results (beyond being able to say it didn't make him lose). And Trump's case is very different from someone targeting rivals, because the charges progressed independently of whether he stayed in the race. Whereas for someone targeting rivals, it's very much contingent on them being/staying in the race, and potentially using legal processes to sabotage that race.

@NotThatGuy - All of Trump's prosecutions have come from his political enemies.

@Valorum Trump deems anyone who doesn't show blind and unwavering obedience to him to be his political enemy.

@Valorum: Jack Smith is a career AUSA who has prosecuted both Republicans and Democrats. Calling him a "political enemy" of Trump is simply a lie.

@jpmc26 I think you mean Bob McDonnell, not McDonald. It was not disputed that, when Governor of Virginia, McDonnell (and his wife) accepted $175,000 in loans, gifts and other benefits from a Virginia businessman. What was disputed was whether McDonnell's arrangements of meetings between the businessman and government officials, hosting of events for the business at the governor's mansion and 'contacting' officials about the business's product were or were not 'official acts' within the meaning of the federal bribery statute.

@Lag Thanks for the spelling correction. Yes, that's correct, and the Supreme Court threw it out 9-0. Even left leaning lawyers were saying during the original trial that it was legally ridiculous and would never stand on appeal. You'd have to go after pretty much every politician in the country if you convicted McDonnell, and that kind of double standard is not legally acceptable.

@jpmc26 You presented that as if Smith was McDonnell's judge, jury and executioner, and as if the supreme court found Smith to have behaved very inappropriately. That's not at all the case, which makes your comment very misleading. McDonnell went through due process of a trail and was convicted by a federal judge after a jury's ruling. The supreme court merely said the court (not Smith) used "official act" too broadly. If there is any "double standard", it's that bribery is a widely accepted practice in US politics (and in the supreme court), which is... not exactly an argument in your favour.

@jpmc26 Also, you found 1 case from almost a decade ago, in a 20+ year career. And for that case, it's not clear whether Smith even did anything wrong (you just expect people to infer this, based on their biases). EVERY prosecutor has some overturned prosecutions. And this is your go-to example to support "Smith has a long history of prosecuting these political hit-piece cases"? This is your best example? Seriously? It's unfortunately all too common in today's world for people to draw conclusions based on biases and emotional appeals, instead of based on evidence, data and fact-based arguments

@jpmc26 "You'd have to go after pretty much every politician in the country if you convicted McDonnell" - and some Supreme Court justices.

@NotThatGuy https://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2023/jul/4/jack-smiths-record-rife-mistrials-overturned-convi/ Renzi's pardon was given due to misconduct on the part of Smith or his team. McDonnell is an extremely clear cut case, though. He did not do anything illegal, and I recall Larry J. Sabato explaining how ridiculous it was at the time. But it drained McDonnell of millions of dollars for his defense and ruined a solid political career for someone who ran his state effectively; he even had to sell his home. It's an excellent example of what this answer is talking about.

@NotThatGuy Your assertion that bribery is an accepted practice mischaracterizes what McDonnell did. Part of the reason the case was thrown out is because there was no evidence that McDonnell actually showed any kind of favoritism or preference to the people giving him the gifts, which means these weren't bribes. Innocent until proven guilty is a foundational principle of law. Would it have been better if he hadn't accepted the gifts? It certainly eliminate any appearance of impropriety. But did he actually do anything meaningful in return? That's the question, and Court agreed he didn't.

@jpmc26 "due to misconduct" ... as asserted by Trump (as your own link says), as if I'd agree that his legal opinion means anything. Since you mentioned "political hit-pieces", what you just linked is a pretty good example of that. At least there are a few more examples. We already spoke about how poor of an example McDonnell is. From a 2 second Google search, Silver doesn't seem much better - comparably overturned because the supreme court interpreted corruption more narrowly. For Edwards and Menendez, it's hardly a sign of wildly meritless charges when the jury couldn't make a decision.

@jpmc26 Also, remind me again how there's some egregious "double standard". Was that supposed to be the evidence of that? Because of 5-6 cases mentioned, 3 are democrats. If anything, you just showed that there isn't a double standard, that both sides are treated similarly. So good job you, I guess. Did you forget to read your own sources? Or are you going to argue that actually there is a double standard, trust me bro, even though your own sources suggest otherwise. Maybe you'll argue it's not across party lines, while keeping it just vague enough so your claim can't be tested or proven wrong

@jpmc26 "Your assertion that bribery is an accepted practice..." - questionable phrasing that makes it sound like I approve of bribery, when in fact I said closer to the opposite. But anyway, I'll assume you didn't intend that. You trying to shift the discussion to debating whether it's bribery is just an attempt to sidestep the reality that enough people in the legal system thought it was, to find McDonnell guilty. That entirely undermines your accusation that Smith behaved inappropriately. Whether it's bribery is an entirely different discussion (which I'm not really interested in).

@NotThatGuy "questionable phrasing that makes it sound like I approve of bribery, when in fact I said closer to the opposite." Now see, this is the kind of shit they do to Trump. What I said does not sound anything like that; it restated an assertion you made, which anyone can go read two messages before, to clarify the context of my reply. Is it any wonder that I don't believe what you say when you can't even be honest about what is right in front of you? That aside, all it means is that Smith successfully misled a jury about what the law says, which proves my point.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

It's not important whether the President can legally do these things, because the rules are so easily circumvented.
In theory the Judicial Branch and the Department of Justice are independent of the executive branch. But in reality the Attorney General (head of the Department of Justice) is appointed by the President, and can be fired at any time if they do something the President disapproves of. In theory the President cannot and should not influence the decisions of the Attorney General, but in reality if they get together in a room where there are no recordings it's virtually impossible to prove it happened. It's also impossible to prevent a President from choosing to appoint only an Attorney General who will do what he says.
There are two checks and balances that are supposed to prevent this (apart from the assumption that Presidents and Attorneys General will behave honourably). Those are 1) the impeachment power of the legislature 2) the ability of the electorate to vote out a President who violates this rule.
President Trump has already signalled his willingness to violate the independence of the Department of Justice by threatening to prosecute his enemies, and to get the cases against himself thrown out. It is virtually certain that his new Attorney General, whoever it is, will abandon all cases against Trump. If that doesn't happen feel free to downvote, but I'm confident that won't be the case.
In the current climate it's hard to imagine that the legislature would impeach and convict Donald Trump for doing those things. And the American electorate have already shown that they are OK with a President who commits criminal acts and interferes with judicial independence. In any case the posts by Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez are intended to state that President Trump will indeed try to do these things, and will probably get away with it, unless there is action by the electorate - such as voting in Senators and Representatives who would in fact impeach him if he did them. Ultimately the responsibility to prevent Presidential abuse of power lies with the electorate.
With thanks to @264champagnebottlesonice, many Republicans promote the "Unitary Executive Theory, in which the Justice Department isn't even theoretically independent of the Executive. They could certainly use this to persuade the legislature - and possibly the courts - that he was justified in directing the Justice Department to do anything he wanted.
The above shows how the President could prosecute his political enemies: and as sfxedit correctly points out, simply prosecuting someone can cause them significant trouble, even if they are eventually exonerated. However the judges (and jury) would decide actual guilt or inocence in a case. But the President also has the power to appoint judges, especially Supreme Court justices who would be expected to ultimately decide a high profile case. Three of the nine are already Trump appointees, and were selected for their views sympathetic to Trump. It is likely that he will appoint more and more judges who agree with his views.
(For anyone thinking this doesn't answer the question, the question was not "Can a President legally do this" it was "Does a President have the power to do this." Those are two different things.)

I think that many in GOP even reject that theory that the DOJ is independent even in theory -- they prefer "unitary executive", etc.

E.g. https://verdict.justia.com/2023/06/19/the-misguided-unitary-executive-theory-gains-ground

@264champagnebottlesonice I'm going to bring that into the answer, if that's OK.

The judicial system and the courts are a separate branch of government. The Attorney General is an executive department position at the head of an executive branch department, the Justice Department. Yes, traditionally, presidents have distanced themselves from Justice Department operations, but this separation is outside of the "separation of powers" and equal branches of government concept. 264bottles brought this up in terms of the "unitary executive" theory, but I think its not even necessary to invoke that theory.

The Justice Department isn't unique in being an executive department where the president typically does not step in to make decisions. Regulatory agencies like the FDA, for example, do not typically approve and reject pharmaceutical drugs on the whims of the president. But that's all distinct from the concept that keeps the Judicial Branch and Executive Branch separate.

@BryanKrause I'm betting that the FDA independence will change if RFK jr is in charge of health.

The primary check would ordinarily be for judges to refuse to cooperate, and/or to prohibit the President and his men from taking these actions. But this only works is there are not enough judges in the right judicial posts who are willing to cooperate with the President's actions given some dubious, but colorable, legal theory to justify the action.

@BryanKrause There's a profound difference between "the President usually lets them get on with their work, in the interest of the country as a whole" and "the President can't tell them what to do, or at least dismiss key staff on the spot and appoint people who will do as they're told".

@ohwilleke: It's not just judges refusing to act that Trump has to worry about. It's also judges running out the clock. He has four years, starting in January, to prosecute whoever he wants to prosecute, and then that's it, somebody else will be president, and who knows if that person will want to continue whatever Trump started? We've already seen from the Trump cases that prosecutions can easily go for months or longer, so four years is long enough to get a basic case through, but maybe not if everything goes up to SCOTUS and back.

The answer is not clear.
Precedents were created during the Global War on Terror. If the government can designate individuals as terrorist with limited legal oversight, and then apply 'extraordinary measures' to terrorists, then it can apply those measures to anyone. Applying the GWOT precedents to US citizens, and especially to US legislators, would clearly shatter precedent. But the legality would have to be tested by the Supreme Court.

The Supreme Court seems to be the check and balance here. Has a president ever ousted members of the court in order to get the verdict they were after? Sounds like something they could do but not quietly and possibly not within four years? More concerning, would extraordinary measures be legally challenged before they are applied or after? (if the latter, it renders the court much less effective as a check and balance)

The president cannot remove members of the court. Only congress can do that via the impeachment process.

FDR tried to add extra members to get the verdict he was after. (There being nine justices is just tradition, it's not actually a requirement.) As I recall this idea was roundly criticized and never went anywhere.

@SebastianRedl But if President-elect Trump can get the votes in the House and Senate, couldn't he pack the court instead so the Supreme Court rules however he wants?

@cocomac In theory, but finding legislators willing to do so (or more specifically, are stupid enough to do so) would be a hard ask. It would set a precedent that court expansion is okay, meaning that the next time Democrats hold the government they're basically free to do so as well. This is especially a bad move because at this point the Supreme Court already has a conservative majority, so there's not much of a need to start stacking it further.

And remember that after Trump v. United States (2024), as long as it can be slyly constructed as an official act, Trump can do whatever he wants to, without legal repercussions.

@Rekesoft But "without legal repercussions" isn't the same as Trump having that ability in practice. Assuming you're referring to 1 2 3, while I see the very big issue there, IMO, one very quickly runs into the laws are a social contract issue. In other words, there can very much be a difference between legal power and what the rest of the government is willing to enforce/what the people will tolerate.

Recent rulings of the court that was packed diuring the last tenure of trump leave me not very hopeful of this court not ruling in favour of trump (the horrifying "immunity case" comes to mind)...

@Cadence the number nine is indeed a requirement, not a tradition, but it is a statutory requirement, not constitutional.  Changing it requires an act of congress, not merely presidential action.

@phoog But if POTUS has a united Congress on his side, that's not a huge impediment. We don't know yet how the House will lean after this election.

@cocomac Considering that the electorate voted in favor of someone who promised to take actions like this, they seem to be willing to tolerate quite a bit. And there are plenty of members of Congress who are OK with him as well, they didn't convict him in either of his impeachment trials.

@phoog I am surprised to just learn that the court had 10 justices at one point. I had been under the impression that it had always been increased when this changed.  I'm also surprised that it ever had even numbers of justices.

@JimmyJames it's not as hard as people assume to run a majority-rule body with an even number of members.  If the body votes to take an action and there are as many votes against as in favor, the action is not taken because there is no majority.  In the case of an appeal to the supreme court, the action under consideration is overturning a lower court's decision, so if half the justices vote for and half against, the judgment is "affirmed by an equally divided court."  This happens fairly frequently because of recusals.

@phoog I am aware of recusals but with such a small number of votes and the inherent terminal nature of SCOTUS, it seems a little problematic. You do bring a new question to mind. Could two very similar cases with opposite lower court rulings come to SCOTUS and both be affirmed in this manner? Probably worth a question all on its own.

@JimmyJames yes, that's entirely possible, though perhaps unlikely: "Circuit splits," where federal law is different in different places because different appeals courts have issued divergent or even contradictory precedential opinions, are a real thing, and while the existence of a circuit split increases the probability that the court will take a case, it doesn't guarantee it.  If the justices know beforehand that they won't be able to resolve the split, they might well decide not to take the case in the first place.

This is probably true but I'm downvoting because it offers no references or examples.

Current answers ignore both recent and historical precedents.
The US has a long history of looking the other way when a President wants to imprison an inconvenient political enemy.
Consider Eugene V Debs, Socialist political candidate and anti-Woodrow-Wilson activist, who was imprisoned for speeches encouraging draft resistance (even when carefully worded not to violate the already-First-Amendment-limiting anti-sedition laws passed in the context of World War I). Or anarchist activist Emma Goldman, who was also imprisoned for encouraging resistance to the draft--and, before that, for distributing information about birth control, in violation of the still-on-the-books Comstock Act of 1873.
Or consider Lincoln's suspension of habeas corpus during the Civil War--allowing the government to imprison people without demonstrating cause and to conduct military trials.
These laws are sometimes repealed and sometimes upheld, and sometimes stop being enforced. But they never go away entirely, and we are currently at a political moment where such actions are more likely to be permitted.
Specifically, the Supreme Court ruled in Trump v United States (2024) that the US President has absolute immunity from prosecution for acts carried out in office related to his core powers, as enumerated in the Constitution.
Of course, the office of President includes being Commander-in-Chief of the US Armed Forces.
Thus, the Court has issued a precedent that says there would be no legal recourse against a sitting President if he, for instance, directed the Army to place his political opponents in a military prison (or have them assassinated, etc).
Is this absurd, wrong, a clear abuse of power? Yes, of course. That doesn't change that it is what the opinion said; if you disagree, don't blame me, take it up with John Roberts.

Both your examples occurred during wartime, when normal judicial rules are habitually suspended. And your later paragraph misrepresents what the Supreme court judgement actually said.

@DJClayworth The USA is pretty much always at war somewhere.

Those were actual declared wars where different rules apply.

@DJClayworth He could declare war on "the America-hating enemy within" or claim the "crisis" at the border counts as a war.

Also, the USA has a long history of killing political opponents (and "opponents" here might just be one who doesn't bend over to american companies' resource pillage), sometimes even pretending that they were killed by someone else. South-america, europe, middle-east, africa, etc. So, the language may have become "simpler" and more explicit but it's just business as usual for them. The face changes but Sir Humphrey is and will be still in charge.

Your interpretation for Trump v. United States (2024) is wildly inaccurate. The landmark ruling holds that the US President has absolute immunity ONLY to official acts within Constitutional bounds that are not regulated by Congress. The Constitution does not give the US President the authority to assassinate political opponents, deploy the Army to arrest people in the US, etc...

@sonnenhund The Constitution gives the US President exactly the authority that the courts decide it does. Trump claims that the Insurrection Act (1807) gives him the authority to do so, and this Court has shown no sign of disagreement.

@sonnenhund: Funnily enough, the dissent says that the main opinion gives the President exactly the authority that you claim it does not (to deploy "Seal Team 6" to assassinate someone), and the main opinion very carefully rebuts every argument of the dissent other than that one, which it simply fails to acknowledge. I'm not sure how John Roberts intended for us to read that, but the omission is rather disturbing if intentional.

In a practical sense, a US administration has plenty of options to "go after" their political opponents.
Consider the 2013 scandal where the IRS, under the Obama administration, specifically targeted tax exempt organizations based on their politics.
Or the 2016 FBI investigation into the trump campaign.
Even the most over the top dictators will usually cloak their behavior with some sense of legality, usually by stretching some existing law to apply to their political opponents.  You can find a litany of examples throughout history of this scam playing out.
It helps when the legal system has extremely broad laws that can snare almost anyone, like the US legal system.  It's just not usually used to snare the political class, who have usually been given the kid gloves treatment when it isn't something egregious and impossible for the machine to sweep it away.
The tldr is that while there's no inherent power in the presidency to jail people at will, their de facto power over the justice department gives them enormous potential to conjure up charges against political opponents.  Charges that might very well stick, by virtue of our laws being very broad, and if they find a friendly judge that accepts some of the wild stretches that prosecutors sometimes engage in to make the suspect fit the crime.
Case in point, one potential Trump pick for AG has already insinuated they might charge Letitia James with conspiracy against rights.

I'm pretty sure your IRS example is nothing. I remember some Limbaugh-radio-type told Tea Party'ers to start tax-free political groups but gave them the wrong instructions. IRS higher-ups issued a memo in case they got a ton of wrong-in-the-same way applications. But Nixon used the IRS to hurt his opponents, so you could use that.

The 2016 case is also a non-example. Investigations into Trump regarding events surrounding the election result and a number of other issues in 2016 were entirely appropriate from an objective external perspective.

If they can't jail people at will, how do you explain Guantanamo Bay?

@gerrit That's actions outside the US, which disables a lot of checks and balances. I think that's beyond the scope of both the question and this answer.

The one about Obama and IRS is false! Lots of TEA-party chapters were established, and apparently a list of instructions circulated that told them to use a specific form to register them and get tax-exemption. However, it was the wrong form, a form that specifically couldn't be used to register political organizations - which was clearly stated on the form! That's why they were investigated! Why not democrats? They didn't have a similar groundswell of new chapters, nor did anyone tell them to register any using the wrong form.

@toolforger He could jail his opponents in Guantánamo?  German Stasi used to declare opposition members as "armed groups" if they were at least three individuals and one had a nailcutter on them, and Trump can learn from the best...

I don't think people can be sent to Guantanamo just at will. I don't know the exact rules, but I'm pretty sure that US citizens and those jailed inside the US are safe. That does not mean that Trump won't change these rules, but Guantanamo is not built for mass jailings so a lot of additional work would be necessary to extend that to a general-purpose tool for jailing people. I'd stick with what we already know, there are too many options about what might happen in the future to discuss that properly.

At the end of the day, it all boils down to physical coercion, and at the end of the end of the day, because it is best equipped and trained, it hinges on the military.
Imagine a war — not a third world war but one that is a bit more serious than the ones of the past 80 years. The President, supported by his party, claims that a "fifth column" is operating within the U.S., uses the domestic threat as a reason to instate emergency measures, starts ruling by executive orders, rounds up the opposition and puts them into camps. The Supreme Court decides to hear a petition for habeas corpus and rules the imprisonment unconstitutional. The Office of Legal Counsel, referencing legal scholars like like John Yoo, rejects the Court's authority, claiming the executive prerogative of the Commander in Chief in war times. The court subpoenas the President with threat of contempt of court. The President refuses to produce the prisoner.
Stalemate.
Who wins?
The one who has the army on their side. The subpoena — indeed, any contested law! — is useless if it cannot be physically enforced.

A POTUS that uses any means necessary and ignores the limits of the law and constitution may have that power granted him.
A POTUS that upholds and defends the constitution is limited to using the powers and laws given by his office.
If a political opponent has gone outside lawful and constitutional means, the fullest remedy is death for treason. It is the courts that ajudicate that.
Those found guilty would have to rely on the mercy of the POTUS, or God himself.
This is only going after one's political opponents if applied  asymmetrically, or those opponents are also enemies of the constitution and therefore the American people whose allegiance is to the constitution.
In this case if one is calling enemies of the people, such as those that perpetrated 9/11, political opponents, then the powers are indeed severe and are only limited by the mercies of God.
If there are errors in this simple explanation please let me know with reason in the comments.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Not really. Otherwise Biden and company would have squashed Trump by now.
But a president with a nominally favorable congress and senate has initially enormous power to create political isolation on any public critics: other politicians, judiciary and media know they are tilting at a heavy windmill by appearing to support criticizing the president. Resistance has to be largely covert or else very common-sense based if made public.
A very deft president (like Clinton) can survive - even prosper a bit - against an opposing congress & senate. And a dictatorial president could make a mess of relations with congress and especially the senators and lose support for bills close to the heart of their presidency.
On important issues related to the everyday economy the congress members will constrain the actions of a president: they have to watch their re-election every 2 years. On foreign policy, defense and trade agreements the senate has to approve major decisions.

Criticism of the President has to be covert? Have you looked at what is and was regularly being said about Trump, about Biden, about Obama, by their opponents from virtually their accession to office?

I mean by seriously ambitious congressmen and senators. People who want to "move on and up" in the political scene. Criticism has to be measured, rational and plausible.

Trump accused Obama of not being  an American citizen. Very early. Are you claiming Trump didn't want to "move on and up"? AOC is criticizing Trump right now. Do you think she doesn't want to move on and up?

Trump gets away with these things - privilege of a sociopath or laziness of rest of us to challenge it according to your viewpoint. AOC wants to be in the limelight. Not sure she's equipped for moving on and up or knows how to build wide support. Most congress members go to law school along the way. But AOC seems to think she can make it on her own terms.

While most politicians were getting their perfectly ordinary law degrees AOC was doing outstanding, internationally recognised,  work in science.

Well, we all live in hope. But it's really early days yet for AOC and her advancement into a more permanent role in US national affairs. History isn't on her side. But,  as Trump proved, history ain't everything.

@Trunk "Criticism has to be measured, rational and plausible." ... I assure you this is absolutely not the case. You're answering a question about an elected representative doing the exact opposite, and this is far from her most unhinged example.

No, not at the current time.  Political opponents or political dissidents would be able to claim First Amendment protection.
Now, it is not impossible that US checks and balances would erode past the limit where this became possible.  But that is not the case as of now, it is not what most of Trump's electorate voted for and aiming to do so would create real risks for Trump.  Overreach is what sunk McCarthy for example.
This type of breathless claims by Ocasio-Cortez is just the flip side of the discourse of fear and loathing that got Trump elected, despite his well known shortcomings.

This answers the question, which is phrased in the present tense : "Does POTUS have the power...?".  It does not attempt to speculate on what might happen in the future.  Nor is it claiming that Trump has no such intent.   It is merely contrasting current laws and precedents to Ocasio-Cortez' claims.

First Amendment protection doesn't necessarily equate to freedom from imprisonment.  Sometimes, first amendment questions won't be settled until trial.  Furthermore, it's not inconcevable that the purported crime could be unrelated to anything the accused has said.  It brings new meaning to the phrase "trumped-up charges."

First amendment protection for what? You seem to be assuming specific charges that they'll be prosecuted for.

Ocasio-Cortez' claims are about the future. By your own admission, you're not answering the question. If you think the Q is silly or unanswerable due to its focus (on the future), vote to close it.

@264champagnebottlesonice I did VTC.  It is both aim to discredit and opinion-based.  Even if the top voted answer engages in future speculation, the question is, again, phrased in the present tense.  If the OP wants to ask about future evolutions, let them rephrase it that way.

What does this have to do with the first amendment? The question doesn’t ask whether people can be jailed for expressing opposition, it asks whether people who express opposition can be jailed. Even Capone was jailed for tax evasion, after all.
